# ReactiveX for Python: how to ensure an exception in an observable will kill the entire process?

Tags: python, reactivex

Currently I'm using [RxPy](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxPY) to manage multiple "threads" (Observables) that read and data from various sensors and upload it to the cloud.  Unfortunately I've noticed that when there's an exception raised in one of the Observables it is only that Observable which is affected and the entire process continues.  This may be desirable in some cases where you want the other Observables to continue but I would prefer the entire process gets killed.

I am currently merging my Observables using `op.merge` so I'm not sure how this affects the behavior.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example